# jhipster 4 , mongodb ; relationship between entities

Tags: mongodb, jhipster

How can i manage relationship between  entities  with jhipster using mongoDb?
Someone have an exemple ?
I don't think that jhipster UML is the best solution .

Answer (score 1):

Update:
You can finally use relationships on JHipster 5.4.0 or higher versions 
as you can see [here](https://www.jhipster.tech/2018/10/03/jhipster-release-5.4.0.html)

Currently relationships are not supported in Jhipster for MongoDb, as you can see on the official documentation:

> Relationships only work when JPA is used. If you choose to use Cassandra or MongoDB, they won’t be available.

You have to do manually using spring data mongodb. You can use @DBRef annotation that allow Mongodb to know that there is a relationship.